# Running a command from Ruby displaying and capturing the output

Tags: ruby

Is there some way to run a (shell) command from Ruby displaying but also capturing the output? Maybe with the help of some gem?

What I mean by displaying is not printing it at the end, but as it appears, so the user gets the feedback of what's going on when running slow commands.

Answer (score 81):

You can run system call like this:

```
`sleep --help`
```

Or like this

```
system "sleep --help"
```

Or

```
%x{ sleep --help }
```

In case of `system` it will print output and return `true` or `nil`, other two methods will return output

**PS** Oh. It is about displaying in real time.

So. You could use something like this:

```
system("ruby", "-e 100.times{|i| p i; sleep 1}", out: $stdout, err: :out)
```

To print data in realtime and store it in variable:

```
output = []
r, io = IO.pipe
fork do
  system("ruby", "-e 3.times{|i| p i; sleep 1}", out: io, err: :out)
end
io.close
r.each_line{|l| puts l; output << l.chomp}
#=> 0
#=> 1
#=> 2
p output
#=> ['0', '1', '2']
```

Or use `popen`

```
output = []
IO.popen("ruby -e '3.times{|i| p i; sleep 1}'").each do |line|
  p line.chomp
  output << line.chomp
end
#=> '0'
#=> '1'
#=> '2'
p output
#=> ['0', '1', '2']
```

Comment: I know those ways of running a command, none of them capture the output into a string and output it at the same time.

Comment: I don't see any variant of `system` that takes `out` and `err` parameters? Is this Ruby 2.0?

Comment: @Matthias for old ruby you need => ("hash rocket") notation, so:
, out: io, err: :out  becomes , :out => io, :err => :out

Comment: system("ruby", "-e 3.times{|i| p i; sleep 1}", :out => io, :err => :out)  NOT WORKING: in `system': can't convert Hash into String (TypeError)

Comment: system with out: and err:, nice!

Comment: I like the last answer - I did not have the idea of using IO.popen() and .each on it. system() does line-output, whereas default `` backtick waits until it has finished.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `system` does not actually take `out` and `err` arguments like that, in any version of ruby I can find. I'm not sure where that came from. It would be nice!

Answer (score 17):

I used `open3` to captured the output of executed shell command from ruby code.

```
require 'open3'

stdout, stdeerr, status = Open3.capture3("ls")

puts stdout
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! It gives you 'results' that you can then work with, and it's part of the standard library.

Comment: +80 that should do it :)

Comment: This does not answer the question: how to both display *and* capture the output of a long-running command.

Answer (score 16):

You can redirect the output

```
system 'uptime > results.log'
```

or save the results.

```
result = `uptime`
result = %x[uptime]
```

see [here](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html). Getting progress information or [output in realtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973771/how-do-i-print-output-of-exec-in-realtime) is more complicated, I doubt that there is a simple solution. Maybe it is possible with advanced [process management functions](http://whynotwiki.com/Ruby_/_Process_management) such as [Open3.popen3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html). You could also try to use a [pseudo terminal with pty](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/index.html) and [grap the output there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154846/continuously-read-from-stdout-of-external-process-in-ruby).

Comment: Thanks. Helped me. Just add the following line, `puts result` . This will display the result in console.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to explore a solution outside the standard library, you may also use [`Mixlib::ShellOut`](https://github.com/chef/mixlib-shellout) to both stream output and capture it:

```
require 'mixlib/shellout'
cmd = 'while true; do date; sleep 2; done'
so = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(cmd)
so.live_stream = $stdout
so.run_command
out = so.stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Ruby docs for the non-blocking form of Open3.popen3:

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3

Although the name "popen3" is not as familiar as the "system()" command, it is currently the recommended method for running system commands from Ruby with several advantages over the system() command. There are several variations in the Open3 class: capture*, pipline*, popen*.

The docs are quite clear, so I won't repeat them here.