# How to execute a program and get the console's output?

Tags: ruby, unix, sinatra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running a command from Ruby displaying and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224481/running-a-command-from-ruby-displaying-and-capturing-the-output)

I have to execute a program on my local server and get, in a variable, the console's output

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code? What error messages have you received?

Comment: What outputs do you want to capture? Other programs' outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output = `echo "hello"`
puts output # => hello
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ irb
1.9.3p125 :001 > cal = %x[/usr/bin/cal]
1.9.3p125 :002 > puts cal
     June 2012        
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
                1  2  
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
10 11 12 13 14 15 16  
17 18 19 20 21 22 23  
24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect output with IO reopen.

```
$stdout.reopen("stdout.txt", "w")
$stderr.reopen("stderr.txt", "w")

puts 'stdout redirect'
warn 'stderr redirect'
```