# How to store the result of .exe file as a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, subprocess

I want to execute an .exe file and get its result as a string to display in my application. How can I do this in ruby?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Running a command from Ruby displaying and capturing the output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224481/running-a-command-from-ruby-displaying-and-capturing-the-output)

Comment: What is that exe file supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has several ways of executing other apps in a sub-shell. The easiest is to use back-ticks to wrap the command:

```
`dir`
```

will create a sub-shell and execute the `dir` command in it, then return the STDOUT output to Ruby. You can capture the output by assigning it to a variable:

```
output = `dir`
```