# equivalent of backticks operator with ability to display output during execution

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for something equivalent of the backticks operator (``) with the capability to display output during shell command execution.

I saw a solution in another post:
([Running a command from Ruby displaying and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224481/running-a-command-from-ruby-displaying-and-capturing-the-output))

```
output = []
IO.popen("ruby -e '3.times{|i| p i; sleep 1}'").each do |line|
  p line.chomp
  output << line.chomp
end
p output
```

This solution doesn't fit my needs since $? remains nil after the shell command execution. The solution I'm looking for should also set $? (returning the value of $?.exitstatus in another way is also sufficient)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following:

```
output = []
IO.popen("ruby -e '3.times{|i| p i; sleep 1 }'") do |f|
  f.each do |line|
    p line.chomp
    output << line.chomp
  end
end
p $?
```

prints

```
"0"
"1"
"2"
#<Process::Status: pid 2501 exit 0>
```

---

Using [open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html)

```
require 'open3'

output = []
Open3.popen2("ruby -e '3.times{|i| p i; sleep 1}'") do |stdin,stdout,wait_thr|
  stdout.each do |line|
    p line.chomp
    output << line.chomp
  end
  p wait_thr.value
end
```

Answer (score 4):

First, I'd recommend using one of the methods in [Open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html).

I use [`capture3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3) for one of my systems where we need to grab the output of STDOUT and STDERR of a lot of command-line applications.

If you need a piped sub-process, try `popen3` or one of the other "pipeline" commands.

Here's some code to illustrate how to use `popen2`, which ignores the STDERR channel. If you want to track that also use `popen3`:

```
require 'open3'

output = []

exit_status = Open3.popen2(ENV, "ruby -e '3.times{|i| p i; sleep 1}'") { |stdin, stdout, thr|
  stdin.close
  stdout.each_line do |o|
    o.chomp!
    output << o
    puts %Q(Read from pipe: "#{ o }")
  end
  thr.value
}

puts "Output array: #{ output.join(', ') }"
puts "Exit status: #{ exit_status }"
```

Running that outputs:

```
Read from pipe: "0"
Read from pipe: "1"
Read from pipe: "2"
Output array: 0, 1, 2
Exit status: pid 43413 exit 0
```

The example code shows *one* way to do it.

It's not necessary to use `each_line`, but that demonstrates how you can read line-by-line until the sub-process closes its STDOUT.

`capture3` doesn't accept a block; It waits until the child has closed its output and exits, then it returns the content, which is great when you want a blocking process. `popen2` and `popen3` have blocking and non-blocking versions, but I show only the non-blocking version here to demonstrate how to read and output the content as it comes in from the sub-process.

Comment: Can you put the code which does the same task above using capture3 (and two different arrays)?

Comment: Your code doesn't have two different arrays, it only has one.