# Where is the per-method documentation for ruby

Tags: ruby

I am looking for the primary documentation for ruby functions. As in, the full documentation for the `system` command.

For example, I have seen one guy who is using the `system` command with redirection arguments at [Running a command from Ruby displaying and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224481/running-a-command-from-ruby-displaying-and-capturing-the-output) but someone else who doesn't know that this exists [Getting output of system() calls in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby)

I don't care about the answer to that specific question, but when I search https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ which seems authoritative, all I can find are links to third party "guides" or conceptual learning resources. What I need is the ruby equivalent of PHP's function reference at https://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php Or `perldoc -f` for perl.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org.  `system` is a Kernel method, so http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system

Comment: ruby-doc.org is the target of the first few links under the "Reference Documentation" section at https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [http://ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/)

Packages are organized into "core" and "std-lib".

For example, here is the documentation for the [`Kernel#system` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system).

Comment: Got, it just one step away!