# How to make Gherkin check if the log.info message was printed?

Tags: ruby, gherkin

This is my code:

```
# Execute the constructed command, logging out each line
log.info "Executing '#{command.join(' ')}'"
begin
    timeout(config['deploy-timeout'].to_i) do
        execute_and_log command
    end
rescue Exception => e
    log.info 'Err, timeout, ouch'
    raise Timeout::Error
end
```

I want to check if the message "Err, timeout, ouch" was printed here:

```
Scenario: Normal deploy that times out because it takes too long

Given the event handler is configured to handle events for '^bla$'
...
And the deploy script will take '10' seconds
...
And I expect 'DEPLOY' Serf event '1' to contain data 'status' is 'running'
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your `execute_and_log` method, but you could just use backticks:

```
result = `#{cmd}`
result =~  "Err, timeout, ouch"
```

For continuously capturing output of a command, there are multiple options.
See [Running a command from Ruby displaying and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224481/running-a-command-from-ruby-displaying-and-capturing-the-output)